# Set the depth of expanded structures with ptype in GDB

Tags: c, gdb

Consider the following code in C:

```
typedef struct {
    union {
        struct {
            int x:16;
            int y:16;
        };
        int combi_xy;
    };
} T_MY_STRUCT;
```

Now with GDB I want to look at the setup of this struct. I do so with ptype:

```
(gdb) ptype T_MY_STRUCT
type = struct {
    union {
        struct {...};
        int combi_xy;
    };
}
```

But that result is not very satisfying for me, since all the content of the inner struct (x and y) has been hidden/replaced with {...}. Is it in anyway possible to see the contents of the inner struct? Is there some option to set the nesting depth for ptype? Or even an option to just expand the whole structure, no matter the the amount of nested structures?

As a note I would be good if I could just expand a nesting level equal to the one in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not appear to be any functionality in gdb to control the nesting level that is printed. The code is in /binutils-gdb/gdb/c-typeprint.c, it is quite hard to follow however.

The best I could do was to print an actual instance.

ptype can also be used on an instance. If the nested struct is named then ptype can be used to drill down.

```
typedef struct {
    union {
        struct {
            int  x:16;
            int  y:16;
        }inner;
        int combi_xy;
    };
} T_MY_STRUCT;

void main()
{
  T_MY_STRUCT a;

  a.combi_xy = 5;
}
```

gdb has the following to say on the above

```
(gdb) p a
$1 = {{inner = {x = -8208, y = -1}, combi_xy = -8208}}
(gdb) ptype a
type = struct {
    union {
        struct {...} inner;
        int combi_xy;
    };
}
(gdb) ptype a.inner
type = struct {
    int x : 16;
    int y : 16;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, sad to know that it is not possible. However, nice with clarity.
Yes I know it is possible if the type is not anonymous. Unfortunatley I am not the one providing the structures, and so the struct will remain anonymous. I guess there is no way to deal with this problem then.

Comment: print a will give the field/value details on the anonymous structure but not the type details

Comment: Unfortunatley I am only really looking for the type details. But again thank you anyway!

Answer (score 2):

You can use Python and gdb.lookup_type(), gdb.Type.fields() etc.

Answer (score 0):

When provided the `/o` flag (to include offsets), the inner struct gets expanded, but you'll have to ignore the resulting comments. Here's an example where struct __local_data.private has an anonymous union that is hidden with normal `pstate`, but revealed with `pstate/o`:

```
(gdb) ptype struct __locale_data
type = struct __locale_data {
    const char *name;
    const char *filedata;
    off_t filesize;
    enum {ld_malloced, ld_mapped, ld_archive} alloc;
    struct {
        void (*cleanup)(struct __locale_data *);
        union {...};
    } private;
    unsigned int usage_count;
    int use_translit;
    unsigned int nstrings;
    union locale_data_value values[];
}
```

versus:

```
(gdb) ptype/o struct __locale_data
/* offset    |  size */  type = struct __locale_data {
/*    0      |     8 */    const char *name;
/*    8      |     8 */    const char *filedata;
/*   16      |     8 */    off_t filesize;
/*   24      |     4 */    enum {ld_malloced, ld_mapped, ld_archive} alloc;
/* XXX  4-byte hole  */
/*   32      |    16 */    struct {
/*   32      |     8 */        void (*cleanup)(struct __locale_data *);
/*   40      |     8 */        union {
/*                 8 */            void *data;
/*                 8 */            struct lc_time_data *time;
/*                 8 */            const struct gconv_fcts *ctype;

                                   /* total size (bytes):    8 */
                               };

                               /* total size (bytes):   16 */
                           } private;
/*   48      |     4 */    unsigned int usage_count;
/*   52      |     4 */    int use_translit;
/*   56      |     4 */    unsigned int nstrings;
/* XXX  4-byte hole  */
/*   64      |     0 */    union locale_data_value values[];

                           /* total size (bytes):   64 */
                         }
```